# JSON only returning first character when decoding?

Tags: php, json, jsondecoder

My JSON:

```
{"data":{"addresses":{"bitcoincash":"qzx3k8cq2e66k4glnt2derr5mppzc6xmvuxgsyp778","bitcoin":"1GjKuo1Q9sw8NytE31J5RPnVpYpEzp47hu","ethereum":"0xd7410e84e9c336937637e3cb472ad112c258ede3","litecoin":"LiQCBwuvW4RVuAg2dBNzS4fkviDwi8EBKa"},"code":"PGVD745Y","created_at":"2018-08-18T04:26:23Z","description":"dddd","expires_at":"2018-08-18T05:26:23Z","hosted_url":"https://commerce.coinbase.com/charges/example","id":"ddd","metadata":{"customer_id":"IuYBD5X7ylEV6g0xyTWi","name":"Guest@localhost.com"},"name":"ddd","payments":[],"pricing":{"local":{"amount":"19.85","currency":"USD"},"ethereum":{"amount":"0.063584000","currency":"ETH"},"bitcoin":{"amount":"0.00303719","currency":"BTC"},"bitcoincash":{"amount":"0.03345637","currency":"BCH"},"litecoin":{"amount":"0.32861518","currency":"LTC"}},"pricing_type":"fixed_price","resource":"charge","timeline":[{"status":"NEW","time":"2018-08-18T04:26:23Z"}]}}
```

My PHP:

```
$exec = json_encode($exec);
        $json = json_decode($exec, TRUE);

        echo $json['hosted_url'];
```

It just returns `{` always, in fact even if I put `$json['safasfsaf']` it would still return `{`

What is the issue, the JSON is valid?

Comment: what is the value of $exec?

Comment: It's just CURL, the value is simply the JSON and nothing else

Comment: Whats with the trailing `{` in your example?

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'hosted_url' 
{

Comment: Why do you encode it, then decode it right after? Seems redundant. What exactly is the value of `$exec`?

Comment: I removed it, that was me doing   echo $json['hosted_url']; which as I said returns { always

Comment: Why is it not giving me hoted_url and just always giving me { as the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can get `hosted_url` in this way (ERROR: you missing data `$json['data']['hosted_url']`)

also you can check your desired [output here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a278255b97ecb82d6dee6bb61ae6f9cbb8eca7f8)

```
<?php
$a = '{
    "data": {
        "addresses": {
            "bitcoincash": "qzx3k8cq2e66k4glnt2derr5mppzc6xmvuxgsyp778",
            "bitcoin": "1GjKuo1Q9sw8NytE31J5RPnVpYpEzp47hu",
            "ethereum": "0xd7410e84e9c336937637e3cb472ad112c258ede3",
            "litecoin": "LiQCBwuvW4RVuAg2dBNzS4fkviDwi8EBKa"
        },
        "code": "PGVD745Y",
        "created_at": "2018-08-18T04:26:23Z",
        "description": "dddd",
        "expires_at": "2018-08-18T05:26:23Z",
        "hosted_url": "https://commerce.coinbase.com/charges/example",
        "id": "ddd",
        "metadata": {
            "customer_id": "IuYBD5X7ylEV6g0xyTWi",
            "name": "Guest@localhost.com"
        },
        "name": "ddd",
        "payments": [],
        "pricing": {
            "local": {
                "amount": "19.85",
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "ethereum": {
                "amount": "0.063584000",
                "currency": "ETH"
            },
            "bitcoin": {
                "amount": "0.00303719",
                "currency": "BTC"
            },
            "bitcoincash": {
                "amount": "0.03345637",
                "currency": "BCH"
            },
            "litecoin": {
                "amount": "0.32861518",
                "currency": "LTC"
            }
        },
        "pricing_type": "fixed_price",
        "resource": "charge",
        "timeline": [{
            "status": "NEW",
            "time": "2018-08-18T04:26:23Z"
        }]
    }
}';

$json = json_decode($a, TRUE);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($json['data']['hosted_url']);
```

Comment: I cannot change the JSON, it comes from the server side you see, from the coinbase API, I cannot change the JSON

Comment: @TheCSSGuy your previous json is not valid, but your new json is valid

Comment: Because CURL outputs me plain text, which is JSON, so it needs to be encoded to then grab the hosted_url

Comment: It's still not working for me Bibal, I removed the } at the end, that was from me doing the decode you see

Comment: @TheCSSGuy you can check in sandbox (above Link: output here), it's working fine

Comment: @TheCSSGuy i think you need to decode it first since its already in json

Comment: I have done that, I am encoding it, and then decoding it you see, this is why I can't figure out why it won't work

Comment: @TheCSSGuy first decode once then write exactly want you need for the client side and encode then send/echo to client side

Answer (score 0):

You have error reporting turned off

This error is hidden for you

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'hosted_url'

You can turn error reporting on with this code

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

For your code you need to replace `$json['hosted_url']` with `$json['data']['hosted_url']`

```
$exec = getJson();
$json = json_decode($exec, TRUE);

echo $json['data']['hosted_url'];
```

Also response is already json so you must not `json_encode` it

Comment: I did that, and I just get } as the result, this is my problem

Comment: @TheCSSGuy. . May be you dont need to json_encode the response as it is already json

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that, you are decode json data two time, so you are getting errors.

Hi, i have tried this way.

```
$exe = '{"data":{"addresses":{"bitcoincash":"qzx3k8cq2e66k4glnt2derr5mppzc6xmvuxgsyp778","bitcoin":"1GjKuo1Q9sw8NytE31J5RPnVpYpEzp47hu","ethereum":"0xd7410e84e9c336937637e3cb472ad112c258ede3","litecoin":"LiQCBwuvW4RVuAg2dBNzS4fkviDwi8EBKa"},"code":"PGVD745Y","created_at":"2018-08-18T04:26:23Z","description":"dddd","expires_at":"2018-08-18T05:26:23Z","hosted_url":"https://commerce.coinbase.com/charges/example","id":"ddd","metadata":{"customer_id":"IuYBD5X7ylEV6g0xyTWi","name":"Guest@localhost.com"},"name":"ddd","payments":[],"pricing":{"local":{"amount":"19.85","currency":"USD"},"ethereum":{"amount":"0.063584000","currency":"ETH"},"bitcoin":{"amount":"0.00303719","currency":"BTC"},"bitcoincash":{"amount":"0.03345637","currency":"BCH"},"litecoin":{"amount":"0.32861518","currency":"LTC"}},"pricing_type":"fixed_price","resource":"charge","timeline":[{"status":"NEW","time":"2018-08-18T04:26:23Z"}]}}';
$data = json_decode($exe, TRUE);
echo $data['data']['hosted_url'];
```